# Virtual Hosts in Tomcat 7 in a Windows VM

Tags: tomcat, azure, virtualhost

I'm using a Windows Virtual Environment, supplied by Windows Azure VM.

I'm running Tomcat 7 and want to set up some virtual hosts. When I edit the 'hosts' file and point the url ('partner.example.com') to '127.0.0.1', going to 'partner.example.com:8080' works as expected. But, when I try to access the same url outside of the VM (on any other machine), I am taken to the default Tomcat 7 index page.

Here's my entry in 'server.xml' :

```
<Host name="www.partner.example.com" appBase="exampleFolder"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" >
    <Alias>partner.example.com</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
           directory="logs"
           prefix="partner.example.com" suffix=".log"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
</Host>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: first try locally by pointing `partner.example.com` **not** to 127.0.0.1, but to the internal IP address of the VM. You can get it via `ipconfig` on Windows. My blind guess is that your tomcat binds the virtual hosts to 127.0.0.1, and yet having a default site bound to the internal IP address of the machine. So if your new hosts file works as from outside - this is the issue.

Comment: i tried pointing to the internal ip, but with no luck - same result. basically, when coming from outside, the 'partner.example.com' is not being honored - could the 'name' end up being something else when going through the azure vm (for example 'partner.cloudapp.net'?

Comment: seems like this could also be a domain forwarding issue; if i forward my domain to 'xxx.xx.xx.xx/tomcat_webapps_folder', then my subdomain works...